# AWk script to check and throw error for multiplication result

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I need to multiply column1 and column3 data and need to compare it with column5.
Need to check multiplication and Throw error if result is greater or less than column5 values, though difference of +/- 2 will be ok

Ex - if column1 has 2.4 and column3 has 3.5, it will be ok if column5 have value in range from row1(6.4 to 10.4), row2(248 to 252), row3(22634.8 to 22638.8)
Only need to check multiplication result and Throw error.
File has header too, but need to skip header while validating it.

Correct File

```
a|b|c|d|e
2.4||3.5||8.4
5||50||250
6.55||3456||22636.8
```

Correct file

```
a|b|c|d|e
2.4||3.5||7.4
5||50||251
6.55||3456||22635.8
```

Worng file :

```
a|b|c|d|e
2.4||3.5||6.3
5|50|247
6.55||3456||22634.4
```

Worng file

```
a|b|c|d|e
2.4||3.5||10.5
5||50||253
6.55||3456||22638.9
```

This seems to be ok to check result greater than 2

```
if ($5 > $1 * $3 + 2 ) {print "Error 401: column1 and colmn3 does not match with column5,Field position 5, Linenumber:"NR,$0}
```

But below is not working to check if result is less than 2 and throwing error if result of multiplication is equal to $5

```
if ($5 > $1 * $3 - 2 ) {print "Error 402: column1 and colmn3 does not match with column5,Field position 5, Linenumber:"NR,$0}
```

Comment: Do you need a `bash` script or an `awk` script? Where is the header? Show us how it is present in each of the file

Comment: @Inian...bash script..sorry..pls have have edited my post

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @kvantour..sorry..i will post my code too that i have tried..

Comment: How are you planning to use this in a shell script?

Comment: @as7951 a bash script would be extremely slow and non-portable compared to an awk script and is much harder to write without introducing bugs. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). Why would you want to do that? If you do then why did you tag the question with awk?

Comment: @Inian..pleae give me any script, bash or awk..it would be grate help.

Comment: @Ed Morton..please give me awk script then..that can handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the concatenation of all of the input files you provided as input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
NR>1 { print $0 "\tis " (abs($5-($1*$3)) > 2 ? "bad" : "good") }
function abs(val) { return (val<0 ? -val : val) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2.4||3.5||8.4   is good
5||50||250      is good
6.55||3456||22636.8     is good
2.4||3.5||7.4   is good
5||50||251      is good
6.55||3456||22635.8     is good
2.4||3.5||6.3   is bad
5|50|247        is bad
6.55||3456||22634.4     is bad
2.4||3.5||10.5  is bad
5||50||253      is bad
6.55||3456||22638.9     is bad
```

You didn't show us what the expected output would be but hopefully you can massage the above o get what you want.

Comment: or `($5-$1*$3)^2 > 4`

Comment: Hi @Ed Morton.. I don't want any output..
Just want to print only the bad records rows with header in another file , those have multiplication result deviation of more than +/- 2.

Comment: `want to print only the bad records rows...` - **THAT** is output. Edit your question to show it.